# Is branching necessary when proving a sum of non-negative terms?

Tags: z3

Consider an inequality system of N inequalities and N variables a1..aN of uninterpreted sort:

```
(a1==a1 ? 1 : 0) + ... + (a1==aN ? 1 : 0) >= 1
(a2==a1 ? 1 : 0) + ... + (a2==aN ? 1 : 0) + (a2==a1 ? -1 : 0) >= 1
...
(aN==a1 ? 1 : 0) + ... + (aN==aN ? 1 : 0) + (aN==a1 ? -1 : 0) + ... + (aN==a(N-1) ? -1 : 0) >= 1
```

This inequality system has a property that for each term that has -1 in it, there is a term with 1 that has exactly the same guard (for example, `a2==a1` in the second inequality). This property allows regrouping the terms in such a way that each summand is guaranteed to be non-negative. Also, each inequality contains a term whose guard is trivially true (for example, `a1==a1` in the first equality). Therefore, we can conclude that the inequalities are guaranteed to always hold **without** branching on whether any of the variables a1..aN are equal to each other.

Here is an encoding of the inequality system for N=3 into smt2 (`auto_config false` does not seem to have an effect here, but I added it because we need it for the more general problem):

```
(set-option :auto_config false)
(declare-sort Address 0)
(declare-fun a1 () Address)
(declare-fun a2 () Address)
(declare-fun a3 () Address)
(assert
   (not
      (and
         (<= 1.0 (+ (ite (= a1 a1) 1.0 0.0) (ite (= a1 a2) 1.0 0.0) (ite (= a1 a3) 1.0 0.0)))
         (<= 1.0 (+ (ite (= a2 a1) 1.0 0.0) (ite (= a2 a2) 1.0 0.0) (ite (= a2 a3) 1.0 0.0) (ite (= a2 a1) (- 1.0) 0.0)))
         (<= 1.0 (+ (ite (= a3 a1) 1.0 0.0) (ite (= a3 a2) 1.0 0.0) (ite (= a3 a3) 1.0 0.0) (ite (= a3 a1) (- 1.0) 0.0) (ite (= a3 a2) (- 1.0) 0.0)))
      )
   )
)
(check-sat)
```

If I run Z3 with different N, I get that it scales exponentially. If I check the trace generated with `trace=true proof=true`, I see many `[push]` and `[pop]` entries, which (as far as I understand) mean that Z3 branches.

My question is: is there a configuration option I could enable or additional contraints I could add to help Z3 to avoid branching?

I tried the following:

1. Assuming that variables a1..aN are different from each other.
2. Rearranging the terms into non-negative groups (putting them under the same guard).
3. Asserting that groups are non-negative.
4. Both 2 and 3 together.

All of these changes improve the scalability, but the runtime still remains exponential.

A side note: the general problem I am trying to solve almost always involves quantifiers and more complex arithmetic expressions, but it is always guaranteed that the terms can be groupped into non-negative groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your constraints, as stated, do not restrict the search space at all, I don't think you can do any better than this.

This sort of "cardinality" problems are actually best addressed with:

- Use QF_LIA
- Express your constraints using pseudo-boolean predicates. Search for the phrase "Pseudo-boolean" in [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html).

But these tricks will only help if you actually had constraints that limited the search space in some way. They might still be worth a try though. Since you presented an abstract version of your problem, it's hard to opine on the applicability to your real issue.